# How does Linux system synchronize wtmp and /var/run/utmp?

Tags: logs, pam, w

Linux system normally stores current user login information in `/var/run/utmp`, and stores historical information in `/var/log/wtmp`.

So, how does it synchronize information between them,

1. When a login happens, does it write to both of these files or does it merge them later?
2. /var/run/utmp is not supposed to be persistent, and it will be a lost at system shutdown or reboot?

Comment: I think `utmp` is actually created/replaced by init at boot.  `man utmp` has some clues about this.

Answer (score 7):

In `libmisc/utmp.c` (for Debian in the source of the `login` package) line 301 the comment for `setutmp()` reads:

```
/*
 * setutmp - Update an entry in utmp and log an entry in wtmp
 *
 *      Return 1 on failure and 0 on success.
 */
```

Actually `/var/run/utmp` is updated first immediately followed by writing the log by calling `updwtmp()` (if PAM if used, PAM writes the log). In both cases
both the information is written explicitly and not synced, so your point 2 is not relevant.

To find this on a Debian system. First guess who could do the writing (kernel, `login` command). Search `utmp` and `wtmp` strings in kernel doesn't give much info. So use `dpkg -S $(which login)` to find the package name where `login` comes from and google for `debian login package`. That will lead you to `shadow*.tar.gz` in those sources you will find the code that writes `utmp` and `wtmp`.